# How laravel post redirection works?

Tags: laravel, redirect, post

I have some confusion in laravel `post` method redirection. 
I have to post data from form. Once the data has been post, I have to retrieve the data and store it into the db and get some data related to the post data and pass the data to laravel.

Here, I have used the `redirect()` function to redirect to the particular route.

When I redirect with data mean it not get the data only way to use the session to get the data

I mean push the data in session and then retrieve in view.

how to pass the data to another view when post method ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `with()` method of laravel to send the data to another view as

```
return Redirect::route('your_redirect_url')->with('data' => $data);
```

But it will also store data in the session only, so you can access it as

```
Session::get('data')
```

Comment: thanks for the reply i really appreciate your answer !